# UIAVerify and Inspect are showing different UI elements

Tags: c#-4.0, mfc, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I'm trying to get some automated UI testing in place for a legacy MFC application.  Using Microsoft's UI Automation library has been really smooth and easy in C# to get tests in place.

The MFC application under test contains a tab control as the "main" root element, and that tab control houses most of the application.  There's also a few buttons outside the tab control.  From a high level, the UI tree looks like this:

```
window
   -Tab control <- most things live in here
   -Button
   -Button
   -Button
   -Button
```

Tabs are added to the tab control dynamically, but that has not been a problem for UI Automation.

However, there's 2 tabs in the application that do not have any controls listed in UI Automation or UIAVerify.  The controls do show up in Inspect.  There's nothing special about the problem tabs.  They're the same as all the other tabs in the application.

Is there a reason why some parts of an MFC application won't show up in UI Automation or UIAVerify?

Comment: Inspect has two discovery modes: UIA and MSAA. MSAA is the legacy technology. There are bridges from MSAA to UIA. MFC apps (unless coded differently) are only seen through MSAA, and then the information is promoted to UIA. How do you use inspect, using UIA or MSAA? (the combobox in the upper left corner)?

Comment: @SimonMourier Inspect was on UIA.  When I switched it to MSAA, the controls on the problem tabs no longer show up in Inspect.  I went digging around the source code, trying to find something different between the working / not working tabs.  There wasn't anything obvious.

Comment: Maybe a cache issue. Do you see the same differences with some .NET code?

Comment: @SimonMourier I just fired up a WPF app that has a tab control (still using MSAA in Inspect), and all the controls show up fine.

Comment: I meant with .net code (c#, vb.net, etc.) :)

Comment: @SimonMourier I'm not quite sure I understand.  The WPF app is written in C#.